Lift of cycles in fundamental group of flat torus to $n$ sheeted covering
Consider the flat torus $T$ and its fundamental group $\pi(T,x_0) \cong \langle a,b \mid ab=ba\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ for some base point $x_0$. Let $p$ be a $n$ sheeted covering space of $T$. I am wondering how $a^kb^l\in\pi(T,x_0)$ with $k+l<n$ are lifted to the covering space through $p$.
By the homotopy lifting property, $a^kb^l$ lifts to some equivalence class of homotopic paths but does the cycle property in $T$ around the basepoint $x_0$ imply that all paths in this equivalence class have to contain $k+l$ elements of $p^{-1}(x_0)$? Additionally, how does the lift of  $a^kb^l$ formally behave with respect to the lift of $a^kb^{l-1}$? How does one "add" the additional $b$?
I know the theorems and properties of covering spaces, but I am lacking the tools to tackle such concrete questions, unfortunately.
